# Array map method is not showing list in Class Based Component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-component, react-class-based-component

I have Parent component `FoodBox.js` and it's child component `FoodItems.js`. I'm trying make a list of food items stored in the parent comp. and using `map()` method for it but `<ul>` is showing empty.

Here is `FoodBox.js`

```
const FOOD_ITEMS = [
{ id: "01", name: "Pizza" },
{ id: "02", name: "Burger" },
{ id: "03", name: "Sushi" },
{ id: "04", name: "Pasta" },
{ id: "05", name: "Soup" },
{ id: "06", name: "Cake" },
];

class FoodBox extends Component {
constructor() {
    super();
}
render() {
    const foodList = (
        <ul>
            {FOOD_ITEMS.map((item) => {
                <FoodItems key={item.id} name={item.name} />;
            })}
        </ul>
    );
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <div className={classes.searchBox}>
                <input type="search" placeholder="Search food..." />
            </div>
            <div className={classes.foodWrap}>{foodList}</div>
        </Fragment>
    );
}
}
```

Here is `FoodItems.js`

```
class FoodItems extends Component {
render() {
    return <li className={classes.item}>{this.props.name}</li>;
}
}
```

Comment: You aren't returning in your `map()`

Comment: You should return `return <FoodItems key={item.id} name={item.name} />;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `map` has brackets `{}` which expects a return value

```
<ul>
     {FOOD_ITEMS.map((item) => {
        return <FoodItems key={item.id} name={item.name} />;
     })}
</ul>
```

If you want to return value directly in `map`. You can remove `{}` like below

```
<ul>
    {FOOD_ITEMS.map((item) => 
        <FoodItems key={item.id} name={item.name} />;
    )}
</ul>
```

Comment: This is either a typo or duplicate. Vote to close